# How to update the Material table in react js after CRUD operations?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern, material-table

I've used Material table (code appended below) and tried looking out for many references but couldn't find an appropriate solution to my problem. The table is displayed fine, but the problem starts when any data is added, updated. It doesn't get reflected unless the page is refreshed. Few ways that I've tried is updating state but doesn't help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, Modal, TextField, Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const baseUrl =
  "http:localhost:5000/designation/";

const columns = [
  { title: "name", field: "name" },
  { title: "descrpition", field: "description" },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  },
  iconos: {
    cursor: "pointer",
  },
  inputMaterial: {
    width: "100%",
  },
}));

export default function Test() {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [modalAddDesignation, setModalAddDesignation] = useState(false);
  const [modalEditDesignation, setModalEditDesignation] = useState(false);

  const [designation, setDesignation] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setDesignation((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const allDesignation = async () => {
    await axios.get(baseUrl).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setData(response.data);
    });
  };

  const addNewDesignation = async () => {
    await axios.post(baseUrl, designation).then((response) => {
      setData(data.concat(response.data));
      console.log(data.concat);
      openclosemodalAddDesignation();
    });
  };

  const editDesignation = async () => {
    await axios.put(baseUrl + designation.id, designation).then((response) => {
      var dataNew = data;
      dataNew.map((designation) => {
        if (designation.id === designation.id) {
          designation.name = designation.name;
          designation.description = designation.description;
        }
      });
      setData(dataNew);
      openclosemodalEditDesignation();
    });
  };

  const designationopen = (designation, cast) => {
    setDesignation(designation);
    cast === "Edit" && setModalEditDesignation(true);
  };

  const openclosemodalAddDesignation = () => {
    setModalAddDesignation(!modalAddDesignation);
  };

  const openclosemodalEditDesignation = () => {
    setModalEditDesignation(!modalEditDesignation);
  };
  useEffect(async () => {
    await allDesignation();
     await editDesignation();
  }, []);

  const bodyDesignationAdd = (
    <div className={styles.modal}>
      <h3>Add Designation</h3>

      <TextField
        name="name"
        className={styles.inputMaterial}
        label="Designation"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <TextField
        name="description"
        className={styles.inputMaterial}
        label="Description"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div align="right">
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => addNewDesignation()}>
          Create
        </Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={openclosemodalAddDesignation}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  const bodyDesignationEdit = (
    <div className={styles.modal}>
      <h3>Edit Designation</h3>
      <TextField
        name="name"
        className={styles.inputMaterial}
        label="Designation"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={designation && designation.name}
      />
      <br />
      <TextField
        name="description"
        className={styles.inputMaterial}
        label="Description"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={designation && designation.description}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div align="right">
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => editDesignation()}>
          Update
        </Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={openclosemodalEditDesignation}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={openclosemodalAddDesignation}>
          Create
        </Button>
        <MaterialTable
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          actions={[
            {
              icon: "edit",
              tooltip: "Edit",
              onClick: (event, rowData) => designationopen(rowData, "Edit"),
            },
            {
              icon: "delete",
              tooltip: "Delete",
              onClick: (event, rowData) => (rowData, "Delete"),
            },
          ]}
          options={{
            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
          }}
          localization={{
            header: {
              actions: "Action",
            },
          }}
        />

        <Modal
          open={modalAddDesignation}
          onclose={openclosemodalAddDesignation}
        >
          {bodyDesignationAdd}
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          open={modalEditDesignation}
          onclose={openclosemodalEditDesignation}
        >
          {bodyDesignationEdit}
        </Modal>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your call has `CORS error` and second issue in your variable declaration like `designation.id === designation.id`

Blow code replace to fix your both issue, now data updated on both requests

```
const addNewDesignation = async () => {
    await axios.post(baseUrl, designation).then((response) => {
      const newData = data.concat(response.data)
      setData(newData);
      openclosemodalAddDesignation();
    });
  };

  const editDesignation = async () => {
    await axios.put(baseUrl + designation.id, designation, {headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }}).then((response) => {
      const dataNew = [...data];
      dataNew.map((_designation) => {
        if (_designation.id === designation.id) {
          _designation.name = designation.name;
          _designation.description = designation.description;
        }
      });
      setData(dataNew);
      openclosemodalEditDesignation();
    });
  };
```

Comment: accept the answer if useful for you. and vote up if you want.